# Just installed security updates now all I get is a white screen

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu fails to boot after kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103546/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-after-kernel-update)

I updated the section entitled security updates, now when I try to boot normally I now get a white screen where I would normally log in.

Comment: Do you remember which updates got installed? do yo have any propietary graphics drivers installed?

Comment: We cannot be sure that the OP underwent a kernel update unless he mentions it himself. It is very likely that he did, but we can't be a hundred percent sure.