# Ubuntu fails to boot after kernel update

Tags: 11.10, boot

I made a clean installed of Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit without a problem. It came with kernel version 3.0.0.12.

I rebooted twice with no problem. After this I applied all the recommended updates from "Update Manager" including the kernel version 3.0.0.15.

After this the system doesn't start anymore in normal boot mode. After the GRUB menu the screen remains black and there are no error messages but the “GNOME Login Sound” can be heard.

I have to boot with recovery mode to use the system. I did this clean install because I had the same problem after the kernel update a few weeks ago and didn't find any solution to fix it.

My system is a Dell Latitude E5510, integrated Intel graphics,  with Ubuntu 11.10 booting and running from an external USB HDD.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 3):

Both of you answers where helpful.

Yes it is the LP bug [919350](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/919350) about the Intel i915 and yes the problem was solved with the kernel *linux-image-3.0.0-16*.

Till the kernel update I edited the GRUB to add `i915.modeset=0`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you found a question helpful, press the Upvote arrow on the left of an answer. To mark this question as solved, press the [Accept button](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/6969). `i915.modeset=0` "worked" because the Intel driver is completely disabled, possibly leaving you with a lower screen resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You should [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on launchpad.

In the interim to get yourself up and running, you can boot with the previous 3.0.0.12 kernel as follows.

When you switch on your computer, press and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and your Grub screen will appear.

Select *Previous Versions* and choose your older kernel from the list.

Once you've got to your desktop you can change your grub to remember what you next choose as your grub option.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the line that says `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`

Save.

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot - this time repeat the SHIFT-previous versions sequence again.  Reboot again.  This time it should remember that you booted with the .12 kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You are possibly affected by [LP bug 919350](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/919350) which was reported for a Dell Latitude E6410. It's fixed in the next kernel update (linux-image-3.0.0-16) which was released this morning. So, to fix this issue, refresh your software sources and install the security updates. Reboot after installing this kernel update.